¿Qué está mal en este código?
Mi amigo y yo estábamos intentando crear un juego (en Lua) en el que cuando clickes en la pantalla añada un punto a tus puntos pero nos topamos con que el código no funcionaba y no sabemos porque.
El código:
local boton = player:WaitForChild('StarterGui'):WaitForChild('ScreenGui'):WaitForChild('Click'))


game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)

    local carpeta = Instance.new('Folder')
    carpeta.Parent = player
    carpeta.Name = 'leaderstats'

    local puntos = Instance.new('IntValue')
    puntos.Parent = carpeta
    puntos.Name = 'PUNTOS'

 local boton = player:WaitForChild('StarterGui'):WaitForChild('ScreenGui'):WaitForChild('Click')
    boton.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
        puntos.Value = puntos.value + 1 
    end)
end)

Intente buscar lo que fallaba pero como soy principiante no entiendo porque no funciona.

Lua es case sensitive. puntos.Value no es lo mismo que puntos.value

eso fue un error mio al ponerlo aquí

¿Cómo podríamos identificar el problema si publicas un código distinto?
